# проблемы с Requests в VScode

Tags: python, get, visual-studio-code, requests

Возникла проблема, при гет запросе на любой сайт в vscode выскакивает ошибка:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='https', port=80): Max retries 

exceeded with url: //vk.com (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x109b78fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

При запуске того же самого кода

```
import requests

url = 'http://https://vk.com'

r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
```

через терминал, все работает(код 200)
Как решить? спасибо.

Comment: если сделать: url с https:// не заработает?

Comment: К сожалению, нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

url = 'https://vk.com'

r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
```

Comment: Боже, серьезно?
Наверное, мне нужно поспать. Спасибо большое)